Calculating Electric Flux Through a Closed Surface
I'm trying to solve a problem involving the calculation of electric flux through a closed surface, but it's my first time attempting such a problem and I could use some guidance.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
My attempt is as follows:
Let $S$ be the closed surface composed of the hemisphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1, x\geq 0$ and the base $x^2+y^2\leq 1, z=0$. Let $\mathbf{E}$ be the electric field defined by $\mathbf{E}(x,y,z)=(2x,2y,2z)$. Find the electric flux through $S$. (Hint: Divide $S$ into two parts and calculate $\int_{S_1}\mathbf{E}ds, \int_{S_2}\mathbf{E}ds$).
SOLUTION
For hemisphere $ S_1 $ (where $ x \geq 0 $):
The parameterization of $ S_1 $ can be $ \mathbf{\Phi}_1(\theta, \phi$ = $\cos \theta \sin \phi, \sin \theta \sin \phi, \cos \phi)$ with $ 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi $ and $ 0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2 $ since we are only interested in half of the hemisphere $( x \geq 0 )$.

The electric field $ \mathbf{E}(x, y, z) = (2x, 2y, 2z) $.

The electric flux $ \Phi_{E1} $ through $ S_1 $:
$ \Phi_{E1} = \int_{S_1} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{S} = \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{\Phi}_1(\theta, \phi)) \cdot (\mathbf{T}_\theta \times \mathbf{T}_\phi) \, d\phi \, d\theta $
For  $S_1$:
$ \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{\Phi}_1(\theta, \phi)) = (2\cos \theta \sin \phi, 2\sin \theta \sin \phi, 2\cos \phi) $
The surface element $d\mathbf{S} $ in spherical coordinates arises from the cross product of the partial derivatives of $\mathbf{\Phi}_1 $ with respect to $ \theta $ and $ \phi $. For spherical coordinates, $ \|\mathbf{T}_\theta \times \mathbf{T}_\phi\| = \sin \phi $, so $ d\mathbf{S} $ is the measure of this cross product multiplied by $ d\theta d\phi $, hence $ \sin \phi \, d\theta \, d\phi $.
Therefore, the integral for the flux through ( S_1 ) will be:
\begin{split}
\Phi_{E1} &= \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} (2\cos \theta \sin \phi, 2\sin \theta \sin \phi, 2\cos \phi) \cdot (\sin \phi \, \mathbf{n}) \, d\phi \, d\theta \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} (2\cos \theta \sin^2 \phi + 2\sin \theta \sin \phi \cos \phi + 2\cos \phi \sin \phi) \, d\phi \, d\theta \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} \left[ -\cos \theta \cos^2 \phi + \sin \theta \sin^2 \phi + \cos \phi \sin^2 \phi \right]_{0}^{\pi/2} \, d\theta \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} \left( 0 - 0 + \frac{1}{2} \right) \, d\theta \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{2} \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{split}
Thus, the electric flux through $S_1 $ is $ \frac{\pi}{2} $.
For the base $ S_2 $ (where $ z = 0 $):

List The parameterization of $S_2 $ is $ \mathbf{\Phi}_2(r, \theta) = (r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta, 0) $ for $ 0 \leq r \leq 1 $ and $ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi $.
Given that the electric field $ \mathbf{E} $ only affects the components in the $ xy $-plane, the vertical component of the flux through $S_2 $ is zero.

The electric flux $ \Phi_{E2} $ through $ S_2 $:
$$ \Phi_{E2} = \int_{S_2} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{S} = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{\Phi}_2(r, \theta)) \cdot (\mathbf{T}_r \times \mathbf{T}_\theta) \, dr \, d\theta $$
$$= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2\pi} (2r\cos \theta, 2r\sin \theta, 0) \cdot (0,0,r) \, dr \, d\theta = 0 $$

You have to think about orientation. Presumably the outward-pointing normal points out of the sphere.  Is $\mathbf T_\theta\times\mathbf T_\phi$ giving you the correct orientation?

Three issues:

$S$ should be split up into $3$ components, not $2$ (although ultimately it's as you say, the planar faces of $S$ will contribute nothing)

The normal vector to $S_1$ is incorrect:
$$\mathbf n_1 = \frac{\partial\mathbf\Phi_1}{\partial\phi} \times \frac{\partial\mathbf \Phi_1}{\partial\theta} = \left(\cos\theta \sin^2\phi, \sin\theta \sin^2\phi, \cos\phi \sin\phi\right)$$
Perhaps you've confused it with the expression to which the integrand reduces,
$$\mathbf E(\mathbf\Phi_1) = \left(2\cos\theta\sin\phi, 2\sin\theta\sin\phi, 2\cos\phi\right) \\
\implies \iint_{S_1} \mathbf E\cdot ds = \int_{-\tfrac\pi2}^\tfrac\pi2 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 2\sin\phi \, d\phi\,d\theta$$

Integration limits. On $S_1$ you should have $\theta\in\left[-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right]$ since you are confined to $x\ge0$. The choice of $[0,\pi]$ would be correct if this had been $y\ge0$ instead. There happens to be no difference here because the integrand is independent of $\theta$ and both the in/correct intervals have the same length. Similarly, on $S_2$, $\theta\not\in[0,2\pi]$ because you're not integrating over an entire disk.


You can check your answer against the divergence theorem:
$$\iint_S \mathbf E\cdot ds \stackrel?= \int_0^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} \operatorname{div} \mathbf E \, dz\,dy\,dx$$
In Mathematica (I happened to notice your profile on the SE site):
With[
    {f = 2 {#1, #2, #3} &,
     reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && x >= 0 && z >= 0, {x, y, z}]},
    Integrate[Div[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z} \[Element] reg]
]


Thanak you very much for the explanation. Yes I am a Mathematica user too.
